# Static Files are set but not working. I keep getting 500 error

Tags: python-3.x, django

Can someone please look at the way I have my static files set up and tell me if there is something I am missing? Thank you.

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'
```

Comment: The post works, but when I add an image I get the 500 server error. The image is 125kb, so it is not too big (I don't think).

Comment: I am using Apache2

Comment: Show the view you use to upload the image. What do you see in apache logs? Do you get new file in media directory?

Comment: Do you run your django app as wsgi on apache?

Comment: @DmitryBelaventsev: class AddPostView(CreateView):
    model = Post
    form_class = PostForm
    template_name = 'add_post.html'

Comment: We will need logs output from apache as well. Update your question.

Comment: @DmitryBelaventsev I am not getting any error logs. Just 500 server error.

Comment: @DmitryBelaventsev Yes I use wsgi on apache2

Comment: @DmitryBelaventsev I have gone over and over the code, and it looks exactly like it shows in the Django docs. I can't see what I am doing wrong. I can make posts, but can't add images.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found for this error is:

sudo chmod a+w/'projectmain'/'projectfolder'/media/images